# Swift: Error when trying to import UIKit

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, import, uikit

I'm getting this really weird error when trying to import UIKit in my swift file.

My Code is simply:

```
import UIKit

class Test: NSObject {

}
```

The error I get at 'import UIKit' is:

- Unknown type name 'import'
- Expected ';' after top level declarator

I have added UIKit to my Frameworks folder, the class doesn't contain any code (so therefore there shouldn't be anything wrong with it) and I tried to restart both xCode and my Mac, but the error is still there.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**
Solved:

I tried to import 'Test.swift' in AppDelegate.

Comment: try to import Foundation as well

Comment: also tried that, but then i get the same error on the 'import Foundation' line

Comment: Are you sure that your file has the suffix .swift?  That error would occur if the your code is put into a C or Objective-C file. – If this does not help, go to the  Report navigator and copy/paste the full build log.

Comment: k, found what's been causing the error, I imported my Test Class in AppDelegate. (weird that it caused an error in the Test Class though)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This problem usually happens when you try to import ".swift" file in your Objective-C code, like this: `#import "HomeViewController.swift"`. This is wrong and you should import special, automatically generated Swift header, instead:

`#import "ProductModuleName-Swift.h"`

where `ProductModuleName` is the name of your module (or project) containing the Swift code.

Answer (score 1):

Found good Trouble shooting guide - there is great Troubleshooting Tips and Reminders section!

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_87

Answer (score 0):

The import stuff in swift is case sensitive. Example :

```
import uikit
```

will not work. You'll have to type it as

```
import UIKit
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was because somehow the selected type in the file inspector was **objective-c source** instead of **Default - Swift Source** even though i was using a **.swift** file.

Changing it to **Default - Swift Source** solved the issue for me.

[image]

Comment: How do you do that

Comment: @PeterSchorn Select the file -> Go to File inspector in the right side -> Just below the name of the file check the "type"