# "unknown type name import" error in iOS

Tags: ios

I Had tried to include swift ViewController File in to Objective-C project
but i unable to do it, it shows error like **unknown type name import** how to solve this please any one help for this issue.

Here I Send my Code and ScreenShot.

```
import UIKit
@objc class SigViewController2: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var cameraBtn: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var imageBtn: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var settingsBtn: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var mediaBtn: UIButton!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false

    self.navigationItem.title = "Main";
}
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {

    // Only allow Portrait
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
}

override func preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation() -> UIInterfaceOrientation {

    // Only allow Portrait
    return UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait
}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried simply cleaning and building? Sometimes Xcode just gives errors but doesn't actually mean it.

Comment: Similar issue -[Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29345594/swift-error-when-trying-to-import-uikit)

Comment: I cleaned and build lot of times but i doesn't work

Comment: you need to use "@import UIKit;" here

Comment: You must lost } in other files.

Comment: Not like this..@AmitRaj

Comment: This problem usually happens when I try to import ".swift" file in My Objective-C code.

Comment: I have the same problem

Answer (score 10):

**For Developers still looking for answer.**
Importing `Swift` file inside `Objective-c` can cause this error, if it doesn't import properly.

---

*Let's look at the the error first.*

[image]

*Let's try above* `KJTreeObjC.Swift` *file inside below* `Objective-C ViewController`.

[image]

---

**Solution:**

You've to import it with the help of bridging header.
When you **Created/Copied Swift file** inside **Objective-C project**. It would've created a bridging header automatically.

Check `Objective-C Generated Interface Header Name` at `Targets -> Build Settings`.
[image]

That's the header name we will `Import` now.
You can check afterwards, error would've been gone instantly.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This error is showing because you have imported `.swift` class in your `Objective-C ViewController`. This is wrong and you should import Swift header, instead:

```
#import "ProductModuleName-Swift.h"
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was because somehow the selected type in the file inspector was **objective-c source** instead of **Default - Swift Source** even though i was using a **.swift** file.

Changing it to **Default - Swift Source** solved the issue for me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in my project. I was using swift code in my objective-c code. In any class of your project, you must have imported swift file in objective-c style, like this:

```
#import "MyClass.swift"
```

Please remove that and use forward declaration in .h file, like this:

```
@class MyClass.swift;
```

It will remove all errors and will work perfectly.

Comment: Also Please add MyProjectName-Swift.h in your project and import this in your class in order to use swift class.  Only those swift class can be used which are **public** and inherited from **NSObject**.

Answer (score 0):

What I did: Select the file and check your "Target membership"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GaOh.png)